XPerf/Windows Performance Analyzer Stack not showing names
I'm new to profiling and stack traces. I'm trying to use a stack trace and downloaded it from application insights profiler;however many of the stack names, functions, and so forth don't have a name. How can I solve this?


n/a means no stack was recorded. This usually happens when profiling is stopped which is a multi stage process where first the stacks are disabled and later the profiling events are stopped. If you record the file with wpr then you will see grey regions where tracing was shutting down which can take up to minutes on a busy machine with many cores. If you select these n/a events then the region in the trace are marked blue in the timeline these should show up at the end of the trace.


I'm trying to use a stack trace and downloaded it from application insights profiler


If you're using application insights profiler as shown in below it is very easy to download the traces and you can view it in visual studio also, please follow below.




After clicking on download you can see a zip file which is saved in your local storage. That file can open in vs editor.


In the above image you have opened it in WPA. To get more detail please check this in application insights profiler.
